# integrating Google Translation API and Google Speech API in android

Tags: android, google-translate, google-translation-api

App crashing when i am integrating Google Translation API into Google Speech API in android

**Gradle :**

```
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

// OAuth2 for Google API
implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}



 implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.53.0'){
     exclude module: 'httpclient'
 }
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:101)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.PemReader.readNextSection(PemReader.java:106)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(PemReader.java:135)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.privateKeyFromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:296)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:286)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:210)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:174)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:141)
>           at com.google.cloud.android.speech.SpeechService$AccessTokenTask.doInBackground(SpeechService.java:361)
>           at com.google.cloud.android.speech.SpeechService$AccessTokenTask.doInBackground(SpeechService.java:337)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)

Comment: So, did you find a solution? I have a very similar problem ...